# setTimeout. передача параметра функции в функцию

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток. 
К делу. 
При запуске функции setTime,в нее передаем input, куда выводиться время. вопрос. при повторном вызове через таймер, obj не определяется. и даже если inputs через var определить не работает. только таким образом. вот.
код

```
var id_inter;
    var go = true;

    function setTime(obj) {
      data = new Date()
      hours = data.getHours();
      mins = data.getMinutes();
      secs = data.getSeconds();
      if (hours < 10) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
      }
      if (mins < 10) {
        mins = "0" + mins;
      }
      if (secs < 10) {
        secs = "0" + secs;
      }
      time = hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;
      obj.value = " " + time;
      id_inter = setTimeout('setTime(obj)', 1000);
    }

    function stopTime(obj) {
      clearTimeout(id_inter);
      obj.value = "";
    }

    function times(input_form) {
      if (go) {
        setTime(input_form);
        go = false;
        document.data.start.value = "Стоп";
      } else {
        stopTime(input_form);
        go = true;
        document.data.start.value = "Старт";
      }
    }
```

Если писать вместо

```
obj.value = " " + time;
id_inter = setTimeout('setTime(obj)', 1000);
```

так:

```
inputs = obj;
id_inter = setTimeout('setTime(inputs)', 1000);
```

то всё работает.

Почему?

`https://jsfiddle.net/jL3fhLd3/4/`

Comment: написали бы еще лучше при каком коде **не** работает. и чем не устраивает данный вариант?

Comment: Исправил. Устраивает. просто интересно почему так.

Comment: Интересное поведение. Вообще, лично я, передавал бы аргументы по-другому, например согласно докам `setTimeout(func / code, delay[, arg1, arg2...])` писал бы так: `id_inter = setTimeout(setTime, 1000, obj);` ..... так точно всё работает.  Но поведение интересное.. Подождем пока кто ответит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда вы пишите `setTimeout('setTime(obj)', 1000);` - ваша `setTime(obj)` исполняется в глобальной области видимости, где нет никакого `obj`.

Когда вы пишите `inputs = obj` - вы создаете глобальную переменную, потому и `setTimeout('setTime(inputs)', 1000);` работает. Но в случае нескольких таймеров все поломается - потому что глобальная переменная только одна.

Правильно же передавать в `setTimeout` не строку - а функцию:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  setTime(obj);
}, 1000);
```

Или более коротко если интересуют только свежие браузеры:

```
setTimeout(() => setTime(obj), 1000);
```

Также можно воспользоваться формой `setTimeout` с передачей дополнительных аргументов:

```
setTimeout(setTime, 1000, obj);
```

Comment: точно. и ведь недавно целых два вопроса были о setTimeout и их области видимости.. вот у меня башка дырявая :-/

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ничего, у меня тоже дырявая (см. обновление) :-)